# Advanced custom fields repeater with post object not repeating content

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am attempting to use a repeater with a post object inside as seen here:

[Picture of ACF repeater with post object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzxXe.png)

It is only showing one out of two Reps:

[Rep map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dumAO.png)

Here is the code I am using to attempt to accomplish this:

```
<?php               
$args = array(  
'post_type' => 'find-your-rep',
'post_status' => 'publish',                 
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$i = 0;
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $i++ ?>
<span id="div<?php echo $i ?>" class="targetDiv">
<div class="repCard">
<?php if ( have_rows( 'reps' ) ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_rows( 'reps' ) ) : the_row(); ?>                         
<h3><?php the_sub_field( 'location' ); ?></h3>
<?php $rep = get_sub_field( 'rep' ); ?>
<?php if ( $rep ) : ?>
<?php $post = $rep; ?>
<?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
<div class="fullname"><?php the_title() ?></div>
<?php if ( get_field( 'company' ) ) : ?><div class="company">
<?php the_field( 'company' ); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field( 'phone' ) ) : ?> 
<div class="phone"><i class="phone icon"></i> 
<a href="tel:<?php the_field( 'phone' ); ?>">
<?php the_field( 'phone' ); ?></a>. 
</div>.   
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field( 'email' ) ) : ?>
<div class="email">
<i class="envelope icon"></i> <a href="mailto:<?php the_field( 'email' ); ?>">
<?php the_field( 'email' ); ?></a></div>
<?php endif; ?>                         
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>                         
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
Sorry, there's no rep assigned to this location.
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</span>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I'd appreciate any help/direction to resolve this.

Comment: move `wp_reset_postdata` to after the reps `endwhile`.

Comment: Good call on that; however, didn't do the trick.

Comment: @mark you would benefit from some simple cleanup of your code. It's kind of busy.  Why are you opening closing PHP on every line? Why this? `$post = $rep;` it's not needed. Why are you using `setup_post_data` ? Also not necessary.   But if you feel it is necessary, you can do `setup_post_data($rep)` and remove extra code.
Your code will be much easier to follow if you can clean it up.

Comment: So, is `$rep` the post object? are `the_fields` related to `$rep`?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The answer is here in case others need the assistance: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/problema-withe-repeater-item/